# How to create a JS file with a command DISCORD.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I was wondering if you can create a .js file with it. I haven't found a way to do it. My command reacts to &createfile {name} and it will always create a .js file. My code so far:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'createfile',
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        var fileName = args[0]
        if(!args) {
            return message.reply('invalid name')
        };
        // Create file {fileName}.js
    }
}
```

Comment: The same way you create a file in any Node.JS process, with the built in FileSystem. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the built-in `fs` module. It is built into node, so it doesn't need to be installed via `npm install`.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

// Synchronously create a new file:
fs.writeFileSync(`${__dirname}/${fileName}.js`, "<contents of JS file>");
```

See the [official node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options) for `fs`. This method sets the content of the file at the specified path, and creates the file if it doesn't already exist. You can also use other similar methods, such as `appendFileSync()`, to create the file and/or modify its contents as well.